# "Uncaught Call to StartUpload failed" swfupload

Tags: javascript, swfupload

I've tested my current configuration of swfupload on my local machine, and everything is in a working condition.
But, now, on my live server the script won't upload.

When I perform an upload, the file uploads as one would think, but then when the file is finished uploading to the server, the page turns completely blank(WSOD).
I've tested if the server-side PHP script recieves any data, but nada.

The only indication towards what it might be is the following JS error:

```
**Uncaught Call to StartUpload failed**
SWFUpload.callFlashswfupload.js:454
SWFUpload.startUploadswfupload.js:492
$.fn.swfuploadjquery.swfupload.js:40
e.extend.eachjquery.min.js:2
e.fn.e.eachjquery.min.js:2
$.fn.swfuploadjquery.swfupload.js:16
(anonymous function)/projects/upload.vh/?page=upload:78
f.event.dispatchjquery.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.ijquery.min.js:3
f.event.triggerjquery.min.js:3
f.fn.extend.triggerjquery.min.js:3
e.extend.eachjquery.min.js:2
e.fn.e.eachjquery.min.js:2
f.fn.extend.triggerjquery.min.js:3
$.fn.swfupload.each.$.each.settings.(anonymous function)jquery.swfupload.js:30
(anonymous function)swfupload.js:727
SWFUpload.executeNextEventswfupload.js:747
(anonymous function)
```

Other than that, everything is completely sane.
I've tried said fix on [here](http://issues.fluidproject.org/browse/FLUID-3114), but to no avail.

Edit: The swfupload.js script is stock, apart from edit mentioned.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271105/swfupload-startupload-fails-if-not-called-within-the-file-dialog-complete-hand