# Too much recursion with swfupload

Tags: swfupload

I am facing a too much recursion error when using swfupload in IE9. It works for the first time i load the object, but once I navigate to a different part of the site and come back to the upload page, these kinds of calls start occuring:

> ```
> out of stack space - swfupload.speed.js Line 72: 
>         return this.speedSettings.user_file_queued_handler.call(this, file);
> ```

I never unload the swfupload(flash) component specfically from the webapp.

What is going wrong?

Comment: I am facing exactly same issue on IE9. Have you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Flash object does behave funkily when it is instatiated but not available/hidden on the page.
(see: [SWFUpload startUpload() fails if not called within the file_dialog_complete_handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271105/swfupload-startupload-fails-if-not-called-within-the-file-dialog-complete-hand))

So I ended up re-instantiating the object when coming back to the view containing it. Seems to solve the problem.